# Why does my user defined excel function in Excel DNA return random number if I call the function without parentheses?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-dna

I am making a Excel DNA excel plugin. I have created some user defined function using 'ExcelFunctionAttribute'. Now when i call this function without parentheses it returns a random number.

Suppose my function is:

```
[ExcelFunction(Description= "Hello Function", IsVolatile = true)]
public static string Hello(string name)
{
    return "Hello "+name;
}
```

I have 3 scenario:

1. If I call the function in excel as =Hello("XYZ") it return Hello XYZ.
2. If I call the function in excel as =Hello() it gives error.
3. If I call the function in excel as =Hello it gives a random number like -17453245.

In my this scenario I have not given parentheses. 
So could anyone please tell me Why this happen? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If I call the function in excel as =Hello() it gives error* - it is obvious ... this method takes parameter so you cannot call it without ...  *=Hello it gives a random number like -17453245* less obvious but it's prolly method address ... *How can I fix this issue?* but what is an issue? it works as intended

Comment: I don't want a random number should display, 
Can we manage to give any custom message or error

Comment: `=Hello` is not calling the function. You fix this "issue" by adding the parenthesis.

Comment: =Hello is not calling the function, But if we write this "=Hello" then this gives 10 digits random number,
That i don't want, I want to handle this 10 digits number with custom error or message

Answer (score 0):

The number you see when calling the function with no parentheses is not a random number, but is the "Registration ID" for the user-defined function. It is the internal ID that Excel assigns to the internal name under which the UDF is registered.

When the formula only has the UDF name with no parentheses, the *add-in is never called by Excel*, so there is no way for the add-in to actually return something else like #NAME?.

In some cases one can even build more powerful functions using this 'feature', where you take the function name without parentheses and internally evaluate it.

But for normal use I don't know of anything you can do to work around this built-in Excel behaviour.

Comment: As you are saying that we can more powerful function using this, but how we can write a function that will work without parentheses, and how we can evaluate this.
Can you please provide me some snipped.
Thanks

Comment: @HiteshSingh As I say - your add-in cannot make such a function, since Excel never calls the add-in if there are no parentheses to give it a chance to do anything. I don't know of any workaround and have never seen one mentioned anywhere. The only way is to ask Microsoft to change how Excel works in this regard - it is not in the hands of the add-in, since the add-in is never involved in showing this number.